# MIPS array iteration notation?

Tags: arrays, mips

I have a quick question about some notation with MIPS regarding to arrays that I am confused about.

Lets say I have a value in $t0. It could be anything, we'll say 3.

What I want to do is increment a value stored at that index (the value held in $t0) within in array by 1.

Is the correct notation:`addi array($t0), array($t0), 1`?

Or is it: `addi $t0($s7), $t0($s7), 1 #assuming the array has been loaded into register $s7`?

As an example, if $t0 has 3 in it, then I want to increase the value at array[3] by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPS is a [load/store architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture), so you have to load the value into a register, increment it, and then store it back:

```
sll $t1, $t0, 2     # $t1 = index * sizeof(word)
add $t1, $s7, $t1   # $t1 = &array[index]
lw $t2, ($t1)       # $t2 = array[index]
addi $t2, $t2, 1    # $t2++
sw $t2, ($t1)       # array[index] = $t2
```

Comment: I didn't think the answer would be this complicated. But after some thinking it makes sense, thanks Michael! The only thing I might be nitpicky about is that there is no 0 in front of $t1 when you lw $t2, ($t1), but I guess that is shorthand?